# Access working directory from bash script

Tags: bash, snakemake

I'd like to access the snakemake working directory variable in a post deployment bash script (similarly to how you can access `workflow.basedir` in Python)

I've seen [this example](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#bash-example-1) but it doesn't mention what I want. I can't find any overview of these types of variables in general which sucks because they are massively helpful.

EDIT: $PWD does appear to be the parent of the workflow.basedir but I'd still like to know if accessing the variable is possible in a bash scrip.

Comment: The thing that is the "working directory" from _bash's_ perspective is `.`, and will have a string containing its name accessible as `"$PWD"`. If "working directory" means something else to snakemake, please spell it out very explicitly for the part of the audience here who knows bash and not snakemake. But do actually check, if you haven't -- if snakemake's "working directory" accessible as `workflow.basedir` becomes bash's "working directory" accessible as `"$PWD"`, then your question is already answered.

Comment: _workflow.basedir_ has not meaning in the context of bash. The _working directory_ is the directory you set using the `cd` builtin. Relative pathes are taken by bash with respect to this working directory. Python is doing the same. You change there the working directory with `os.chdir`. AFIK, Python by itself has no idea of something called _workflow_. Perhaps this is some feature from _snakemake_.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can get the workdir with [`workflow.workdir`](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/main/snakemake/workflow.py#L1999)

For a bash script you can pass that value in, but the comments are correct, the working directory of the bash script should be in `$PWD` and unless you cd that should match the working directory you set in snakemake.

Consider opening an issue requesting documentation on the available attributes, I agree they aren't easy to find.  You could try to add a `breakpoint()` in the Snakefile and use pdb to examine autocomplete options of `workflow`...

Answer (score 1):

Idk how your workflow works, but think something like this:

```
rule run_bash_script:
    output:
        "output.txt"
    shell:
        """
        # Your bash script
        echo "Directory: {workflow.basedir}" > {output}
        """
```